# How to center an image in jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

[image]

I am using jquery mobile for my mobile app but have been having issues getting my image to be centered properly.  As you can see from the image, there is more white space to the left of the image compared to the right side.  This is happening consistently for all images on the page.

For more information, pictures that are not as wide appear to be centered but I'm sure there is some difference in the spaces to the left/right of those images as well.  It's just for the wider images that this becomes obvious.

Any advice on how to fix this?

```
            $("#allpictures").append('<div class = "img_center"><div><img src = "'+item.url+'"></div></div><p style = "margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; font-size:15px;">'+item.title+'</p><br/>');

    <style>
        .img_center {
            text-align:center;
        }
        .img_center * {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS, and remove the inline `style` attribute on the `<p>`.

```
.img_center{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.img_center img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.img_center p{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 15px
}
```

HTML in `.append`:

```
$("#allpictures").append('<div class="img_center"><img src="'+item.url+'"></div><p style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; font-size:15px;">'+item.title+'</p><br />');
```

Comment: I'm assuming the margin inline css was meant to be removed in the html?

Comment: @sharataka Yes. Please see `.img_center p{` in the CSS. It has the same effect and does not need to be repeated.

Comment: I just tried this and I'm still running into the same issue where there is more white space on the left of the image compared to to the right.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that reproduces your problem?

Comment: What if you open the page in Chrome, and use the Developer Tools to override to an iPhone?

Comment: None of the images seem to load in chrome...something with the js?